# why are some pages in my start directory not showing in my site map?

Tags: seo, indexing, sitemap

If i generate a site map at http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/, for aromapersona.com, I get 9 pages, however there are a bunch more pages that should show up. For example, aromapersona.com/candle_holder  is in the same "front" directory as the other 9 pages, but doesnt generate in sitemap. Is this because no other pages on my site link to it? Im trying to get these other URLs indexed, and I even edited the site map to include this URL as well as others and submitted to google via webmaster tools, and still nothing. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with aromapersona.com but it will only be able to list pages that are linked to from the initial page you give it (or ones they link to) unless you provide the site with FTP access (which I presume you dont).

If you include the URL's in your sitemap for goggle it should eventually list them, but linking to them from other parts of your site is probably the most effective.

Comment: That is what I assumed. I just didnt know if i was missing something. Appreciate your reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked the website, but do also take the cause is not because of noindex, nofollow, robots.txt, javascript links, mixing http/https etc.

Answer (score 0):

In clear wording: There is no link pointing to the subpage "candle_holder", hence the XML site generator (which works by following links on your site) cannot detect it.

You can add it manually to the XML, but then again, it should be accessible from the site directly.